# Laravel 5.2 + Unicode

Tags: laravel, unicode

when I use a single view file with uni-code in it, it shows the the content correctly but when I make a layout and extends with it from another page it doesn't show the uni-code character it shows ????

`@extends('layouts/custom_layout.blade')`

Comment: The problem seems on only the latest version of laravel i.e. laravel 5.2... In laravel 5.0 it works fine.

Comment: Can you paste the content of your layout file and the view file?

Comment: I have pasted down there.

Answer (score 0):

Check what encoding is used in your other view. Convert it to UTF-8 and it will work fine.

To avoid encoding related problems, use popular IDEs or text editors like Sublime Text or Notepad++ for editing files.

Comment: I have one layout file "layouts/custom_layout.blade" and another "home.blade". If I write the basic code with unicode in home.blade file without extending it with layout then it works fine. But if I use same content in layout file and extends with it from home.blade file then it shows ???? on unicode characters.

Comment: So, check what encoding is used in `home.blade.php` one (or better check both).

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
This is the tag that should be written to support unicode, isn't it?

Comment: @VTxMG, download Sublime Text or Notepad++, open the file in it and check for used encoding.

Comment: I am using php storm 9.0.2

Answer (score 0):

In custom_layout.blade.php file:

````

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="title">Laravel 5</div>
            गृह
        </div>
    </div>
```

````

In home.blade.php file:

`@extends('custom_layout')`

And off course I have used meta tag charset="utf-8" in head tag.

Answer (score 0):

My friend I had the same problem with the unicode characters it turns out that the IDE was causing the problem , I use Jetbrains PHPStorm. I edited the file with sublime and it turns alright.